# How to realize page numbering at the bottom of the page

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering

I tried to change the page numbering to the bottom left/right. My old template makes the numbering at the top of the page left/right. Now I still need the page numbering display at the first page of each Chapter. Can anyone give me some hints? 
My MWE is like this:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[openright,twoside,headinclude,headsepline,headline=2.1]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nouppercase,automark]{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\lefoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\rohead[\partmark]{\leftmark}
\lehead[]{\rightmark}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum
\section{History}
\lipsum
\subsection{Literature}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use markup. We are using markdown here for the formatting.

Comment: I found the other commands in another file. Maybe they are responsible for the numbering.
<code>\usepackage[nouppercase,automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}</code>

Answer (score 2):

**Update** because of the changed MWE in the question

Note that the `\partmark` command does not make sense in your MWE.

Your desired result still seems to be the default behavior of `scrbook`. So remove all code that changes header and footer settings. Especially do **not** use `\thispagepagestyle{empty}` on a page where a page number should be.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[openright,twoside,headinclude,headsepline,
  headlines=2.1% <- changed because of a typo
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[nouppercase,automark]{scrpage2}
%
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 
%\clearscrheadfoot
%\lefoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
%\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
%\rohead[\partmark]{\leftmark}
%\lehead[]{\rightmark}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
%\thispagestyle{empty}% this would remove page header and footer on the current page
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\lipsum
\section{History}
\lipsum
\subsection{Literature}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you want to change page header and/or footer use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead the obsolete package `scrpage2`. Note that the following example only reproduces the default behavior of `scrbook`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[openright,twoside,headinclude,headsepline,
  headlines=2.1% <- changed because of a typo
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% removes the default page header and footer entries
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% pagenumber in the outer footer with scrheadings and plain style
\ohead{\headmark}% headmark only with scrheadings

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\section{History}
\lipsum
\subsection{Literature}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

As @Schweinebacke mentioned the disered result is the default behavior of `scrbook`. So you can remove all packages and changes related to page header and footer.

Do not use package `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class. To get pagestyle `empty` on the first page of TOC and lists use

```
\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

And to get dots between the chapter entries and the page number in TOC set the class option

```
toc=chapterentrywithdots
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  %open=right,% default for scrbook
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  %twoside,% default for scrbook
  fontsize=12pt,
  english,
  DIV = 17,
  parskip=half,
  headinclude,
  footinclude=false,
  headsepline,
  BCOR=16mm,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headlines=2.1,% <- changed
  appendixprefix,
  %cleardoublepage=empty,% default
  toc=chapterentrywithdots% <- added
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel}% <- added

\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}}% if you really want to use pagestyle empty on first page of TOC and lists

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  Title page
\end{titlepage}
\frontmatter
\addchap*{Abstract}
\Blindtext[2]
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapter:introduction}
\Blindtext

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to change the default header entries then load package `scrlayer-scrpage` and maybe ask a new question to get help for the correct settings.

Comment: Thanks, @esdd. I am sorry to change the old codes with a real MWE. Thank god. In your comment there is still some old codes there.

Comment: I have updated my answer because of the changed MWE in the question.